# Прилагательное от слова "буки"

Tags: топонимика

Есть такое красивое место **Буки** в Черкасской области. Буки -- это, я так понимаю, вид деревьев. Там есть живописный каньон, который по-украински называется **Буцький каньон**.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как по правилам русского языка назвать этот каньон?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Красивейшее место, которое называется **Букский каньон**

Comment: Спасибо! Я так и предполагал, что БУКский.
Аналогично: *(укр.)* узбецький - *(русск.)* узбекский.

Comment: >Красивейшее место

Да! :-)

Его можно увидеть в клипе певицы Златы Огневич "Кукушка". Читал как-то в Интернете про съёмки этого клипа. И фото смотрел с мест съёмок. ТАМ, в *Букском* каньоне снимали. Красота!

Comment: Спасибо Вам за вопрос. Вы меня вернули в детство.

Comment: Парадокс! А за что минус?

Answer (score 1):

Тут вообще-то два, если не три, а то и четыре  вопроса.

~1. Как называется топоним. 
В сети легко находятся два конкурирующих варианта - *Букский* и *Буцкий*.
Я - за второй вариант, ***Буцкий***.

Поскольку хорошего русского словаря топонимов Украины у меня под рукой нет (даже сомневаюсь, есть ли таковой в природе), попробую порассуждать. Топонимы не переводятся. Поэтому, в принципе, каньон на русском должен называться так же, как на украинском. Но с мелкими поправками на фонетику.

а) Вопрос о мягком знаке в топониме, приводящем к невозможному в русском сочетанию "ць" с общих позиций не регламентируется, поскольку в отношении топонимов встречаются отступления от общих правил орфографии ради передачи особенностей произношения языка-источника. Тем не менее в данном случае вероятнее всего будет написание ***"Буцкий Каньон"*** с соответствующим русскому твердым произношением, т.к. обычно при заимствованиях из украинского имен собственных мягкое украинское ЦЬ переходит в Ц независимо от морфологической структуры (Кравець, Луцьк и т.д.).

б) Все это, разумеется, справедливо для тех случаев, когда нет *параллельного* топонима на русском, что, впрочем, для Черкасской области вполне вероятно.

~2. Русское прилагательное от бук - ***буковый***. Других словари не фиксируют, во всяком случае - я не нашел. Но использовать его для топонима я бы не рекомендовал по вышеприведенным соображением.

Спасибо за вопрос, заставил задуматься.

Comment: >2. Русское прилагательное от бук - *буковый*. Других словари не фиксируют, во всяком случае - я не нашел.

"Буковый каньон" -- звучит красиво, мне нравится. И для русского языка имеет вполне естественное звучание. Для туристов я бы так и назвал. 

НО! Только прилагательное "буковый" (например, в смысле "буковый лес") -- оно точно так же звучит и по-украински. А "Буцький" видимо отражает привязку к месту.

Похоже, Вы правы, когда пишете:

>Но использовать его для топонима я бы не рекомендовал

Comment: Перед суффиксом прилагательного -ск- конечные согласные основы существительного, от которого образовано прилагательное, в одних случаях сохраняются без изменения, а в других - чередуются или исчезают:рыбак - рыбацкий, но узбек - узбекский (конечная согласная основы не изменяется и пишется суффикс -ск-). Может, другой топоним, основа которого оканчивается на -к, и чередуется с -ц, но в этом случае правильный только один вариант - БУКСКИЙ

Comment: >но в этом случае правильный только один вариант - БУКСКИЙ  

??? Соан, но аргументацию-то надо как-то поподробнее...
Вы с ходу и без всякого обоснования отбрасываете мою основную мысль, что топонимы **не переводятся**, а транскрибируются (ну или транслитерируются - тут варианты) - и начинаете рассуждать о правильности образования русского прилагательного.   
Давайте еще Казацкую Слободу (коим числа несть) переименуем в Казачий поселок...  
Я в готов согласиться, что Ваш вариант - едиснвенный правилный, по почему именно так??

Comment: >А "Буцький" видимо отражает привязку к месту....    
    
Нет. Логика другая. Основную причину я сказал, топонимы не переводятся.
Но даже если бы был параллельный русский, то никак не "буковый". ***Буковый*** возможно от "бук". От топонима "Буки" возможно только Букский и Буцкий. (Если и Вы что-то подобное хотели сказать, то простите, не понял).   

На всякий случай: Великие Луки - Великолукский [район] (современный вариант) - Великолуцкая [губерния] (исторический). Так что даже тут не все однозначно.

Comment: >Все это, разумеется, справедливо для тех случаев, когда нет *параллельного* топонима на русском, что, впрочем, для Черкасской области вполне вероятно.

Нашёл я сегодня топоним на русском. Там в советское время была построена ГЭС. Названа она была **Букская ГЭС им. Г. И. Петровского**. [Подтверждение.][1]


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%93%D0%AD%D0%A1

Comment: @behemothus, а с чего вы решили, что топонимы не переводятся? *Ниагарский водопад, Бискайский залив, Канарские острова, Елисейские поля, Федеративная Республика Германия и пр.* Топонимы выраженные через прилагательные почти всегда приводятся в соответствие с русской грамматикой (искл. Гранд-Каньон и Иль-де-Франс).

Comment: Вehemothus, так сложилось, что летние каникулы я проводила у бабушки в этом самом селе Буки. Поэтому Букский каньон (в то время его местные жители называли "скалы") знаю очень хорошо.  Может быть, в "губернские" времена и было правильно Буцкий (в совр. укр. яз. этот вариант нормативный), но в совр.рус. яз.прилагательное от топонима Буки звучит БУК-СК-ИЙ. Аргументация - в моём комментарии (выше).

Comment: Отвечаю сходу. 
Nikolja, это интересно, но не 100% убеждает. У нас, простите, Нижний новгород - центр Нежеговодской области, а Великий - нов(о)городской. Образования могут идти параллельно. Букская гЭС - это не топоним. Вот если есть именно каньон - и так что бы без вариантов. А СССР много чего было. Помимо секса.  

Марк Из - а  чего вы взяли, что это перевод? Перевод это Новый Йорк. Ваши примеры - это самостоятельное образований.  

Соан, В Помосковье полно топонимов, в которых их обитатели ставят ударение не там, где надо по "общероссийским" представлениям. Привет бабушкам.

Comment: Nikolja, что ж вы током- то не сказали, что там есть словарная фиксация самого каньона? Да еще объект на гугл-карте? Снимаю все возражения.   
Мне это в голову не пришло. 
Соан, простите за прошлую краткость. По счастью оказалось, что есть еще один коммент. Вы меня совсем не поняли. как приагательное звучит на русском - это я и так знаю. Аргументация - это словарная или картографическая Фиксация (в идеале), бесспорная аналогия на подобных известных топонимах, в крайнем случае - некоей теории "перевода" таких топонимов, опровегающих "буцький". По же сути признаю - признаю Вашу правоту.

Comment: >Nikolja, что ж вы током- то не сказали, что там есть словарная фиксация самого каньона? Да еще объект на гугл-карте?

Виноват :-)

Действительно надо было написать.

Comment: я выбирал между вариантами Буцкий и Букский. Не знал, как правильней.

Ещё думал написать как-то вроде -- *каньон у посёлка/села* (или как там правильней) *Буки*.

.

И вот вариант *Буковый каньон*, как я написал уже, по звучанию мне нравится больше всех. Но это, похоже, наименее точный перевод названия.

Answer (score 1):

При заимствовании топонимов из двух и более слов встречаются следующие формы адаптации:

1. Полное заимствование. Но в тогда пишется через дефис, как тот же *Нью-Йорк* или *Гранд-Каньон*. Получается - **Буцкий-Каньон**. Выглядит довольно непривычно и сильно не по-русски.
2. Адаптация. Перевод слова относящего место к классу объектов (море, поле, каньон) и приведение в соответствие с русским языком слова относящего к месту. Из *Niagara Falls - Ниагарский водопад*, из Canariae Insulae - Канарские острова. Тогда - или **Буцкский** или **Буцкийский каньон**. Последний вариант явно благозвучней, хотя всё равно силно непривычный.
3. Перевод. Переводятся все слова. *Огненная земля, остров Святой Елены*. Тогда от Буки - **Букский каньон**. (ср. [нагасакский,](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%ED%E0%E3%E0%F1%E0%EA%F1%EA%E8%E9)). По-моему, это самый приемлемый вариант, поэтому и не удивительно, что именно он и распространён, наряду с украинским вариантом.

Comment: >Из Niagara Falls - Ниагарский водопад. Тогда - или Буцкский или Буцкийский каньон.

Ну это как-то совсем уж чуднО, простите за резкость. :)

"Буцкский" вообще трудно произносимо. -ЦКСКИЙ. :)

"Буцкийский" --мы же не от слова "буцки" образовываем прилагательное, а от слова (топонима) "буки". 

.

Если выше в Вашем примере *Niagara Falls*, то это у нас тогда *Buki Canyon*. :-) Если уж филологически почудить, то Букийский каньон. Но это конечно шутка.

.

А если всерьёз, то я выбирал между вариантами Буцкий и Букский. Не знал, как правильней.

Comment: @Nikolja, я о том и говорю, что в современном русском Буцкий каньон никак не может получиться. Если считать Буцький самостоятельным словом, то образовывать русское прилагательное нужно именно от него, а не от Буки, как в переводном варианте, иначе, например, вместо Канарских, острова были бы Канисскими (canis - собака, canariae - собачьи).
Переход "кс" в "ц", сохранился лишь как традиционное историческое склонения ряда слов, но не более.